# How to modify BuildConfig.java on my Android project?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an online course and i had these lines of code:

```
String baseUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7";
String apiKey = "&APPID=" + BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY;
URL url = new URL(baseUrl.concat(apiKey));
```

So, the API key apparently had to be set up on the BuildConfig.java file.

I tried to do that, by adding this line of code to the BuildConfig.java file:

```
public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY = 111111111111111111;
```

The first issue is that the string was saved without quotation marks and wouldn't let me compile.

The second, and main issue is that i can't modify that file anymore. Every time i delete the line or add those missing quotation marks, and then try to compile, the line reverts to it's flawed version and compilation stops.

I also get this message when i try to modify BuildConfig.java : "Generated source files should not be edited. The changes will be lost when sources are generated."

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 15):

Values in `BuildConfig` come from the build system. Custom `BuildConfig` values like `OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY` come from `buildConfigField` statements in your `build.gradle` file. The `BuildConfig.java` file is off of your `build/` directory; files in there are generated by the build process and cannot be modified by hand. Instead, examine your `build.gradle` files and find where your API key is defined.

Comment: Thanks! In my build.gradle is written correctly:

    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', "11111111111111111111111"
    }

Comment: The solution for this, for anyone landing on this comment, was to write the key like this.

"\"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX\""

Without the backslash and the additional quoting marks its saved as a constant and it needs to be saved as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
buildTypes.each { it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', "11111111111111111111111" }
```

put your API key inside ' '

```
buildTypes.each { it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY',' "11111111111111111111111"' }
```

and sync the gradle again, it'll solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found something like this in my build.gradle file

```
> buildTypes {
>     debug{
>         buildConfigField 'String', ***API_KEY***, 
>     }
>     release {
>         minifyEnabled false
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
> 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         buildConfigField 'String','API_KEY', ***API_TOKEN***
>     } }
```

After building the code, buildConfig.java was regenerated entirely from scratch removing all the changes I made.

The main issue causing this behaviour was API_TOKEN in build.gradle, but it was not declared anywhere in the file.

> The API_TOKEN variable was declared in gradle.properties file

May be you can find the reference there.